# how should I implement sage 200 in php

Tags: sage-erp

I am a PHP developer. I want to implement sage 200 in my PHP application but could not find any php API. is there any PHP api for sage 200.

Answer (score 1):

There's CRM Webservice Framework developed by Enbu Consulting - This allow Sage CRM to connect to other Third party System such as (Sage 200, Sage X3, Booking other accounting system and etc.), you can check the Framework from the website -  http://enbuconsulting.com/crm-webservices-framework/

Answer (score 0):

An http gateway is in development.  There's not much in the way of documentation at the moment.  It's being released as "CRM Connector" for CRM integration this year.  The gateway will work with S200, X3 and some Sage US products.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer is no, you going to have do alot of the development yourself, maybe even create your own API / Rest layer.

That being said it might be easier to write aspx wrapper you can then expose the bits you need with this and if you so wish hook onto them with php.